# XCUITest I use isHittable ,but it occur Assertion Failure? my iphone is ios 12

Tags: xcuitest

my code :

```
if(button.isHittable)//when it returns false,test fail, I can not do button2.tap 
{ 
   button1.tap 
}else{ 
   button2.tap 
}
```

Before I tap a button,I use button.isHittable to get if button can tap. but when i use button.isHittable and get false,it occur Assertion Failure,and my test is fail .I want when button.isHittable is false,i can continue do other step.

how can i do it?

Comment: isHittable is broken. I removed from all my tests.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your identifiers? You seem to have three buttons defined here, but logically it seems like you may only have two (it'd be odd to press button1 if button is hittable)?

What is the error message you're seeing? Can you please paste it? It could be that `button2` is ill-defined rather than the assertion occurring in your checking of `isHittable`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You check if button is hittable but tap button1. You should name your elements properly to avoid mistakes like this.
2. You should not include if-else constructions in your test code. You tests steps should be predetermined to decrease false positive tests.

Answer (score -3):

How do you identify your button with your query? Are you doing it like this?

```
XCUIApplication().buttons.firstMatch
```

Are you using the **firstMatch** property? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/2902250-firstmatch

If so, you have to check if **button.exists** before you check if **button.isHittable** -- if you're using **firstMatch** it's very similar to force unwrapping an optional.

Example:

```
if button.exists && button.isHittable { ... safely tap the button here }
```